Accessing Earth engine asset inside a function when using .map
I am trying to do something similar, I have a feature collection which i want to map over an function, which access image in an asset. The image asset id is a combination of variable inside the function. which i am not able to concatenate because they are in computed object formats not strings. Also i get this error 'Actual value for parameter 'id' must be a constant.' My image lies in subset folders in earth engine assets
year=2019

def getarea(feature):
    
dist_bounds=ee.FeatureCollection('projects/remotesensing/assets/District_Boundaries')
    dist=dist_bounds.filterBounds(feature.geometry()).aggregate_array('District').get(0)
    state=dist_bounds.filterBounds(feature.geometry()).aggregate_array('STATE').get(0)
    
    result_image=ee.Image('projects/remotesensing/assets/CropImages/'+'/'+(dist)+(str((year))))
    clipped_image = result_image.clip(feature.geometry())
    area=clipped_image.reduceRegion(
          reducer= ee.Reducer.sum().group(
          groupField= 1,
          groupName= 'class',
      ),
      geometry= feature.geometry(),
      scale= 10,
      maxPixels= 1e10
      ).get('groups');

    props = {
        'crop': feature.get('crop_name'),
        'area': area
        }
    
    return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), props)


As the error says, Image IDs must be constants, you can't compute one on the fly  (for security reasons).  You can filter an image collection down to a specific ID though.
collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", computedID))

If your images are in a folder instead of a collection, move them over.
